# "A few" + a number : unremarkable quantity

Tags: semantics, determiners, style-manuals

> **A few** is usually more than two (two often being referred to as "a couple of"), and less than  "several". *Few* emphasises smallness of
> number, while **a few** emphasises *some*:
>
> *He's a dull man with few ideas* vs. *He's a **clever** man with **a few** ideas.*
>
> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/few#Usage_notes

However, the following excerpt is contradictory

> *A couple of* is different from ***a few*** in that it does not imply that the
> relevant amount is relatively small. One might say admiringly of an
> exceptional center fielder that *he can throw the ball a couple of
> hundred feet*, but not, except ironically, ***a few** hundred feet*, which
> would suggest that such a throw was **unremarkable**.
>
> http://odict.net/couple/

Similarly contradictory is the idiom **not a few**, which actually means "not few"

> **FEW** (determiner)
> 8. **not a few** (informal) ⇒  [quite a few](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quite_a_few), several.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/few

I hope somebody can help me clarify this whole issue: why does *he can throw the ball **a few** hundred feet* suggest that such a throw was **unremarkable**?

I know "*He can throw it **few hundred** feet*" is not grammatical, unlike "He can throw it **few feet (off/away/etc**.)"

Also, you need ***a*** if it's preceded by *only*, as in *I ate only a few apples and a little soup*.

Comment: I think you would think it a serious matter to fall a few hundred feet from a cliff.

Comment: What @DW256 said. Where is the actual question? Note that exactly the same switch from negative to positive polarity occurs when we preface ***little*** with the indefinite article. Thus, *I have **little** money* means I'm poor, with the strong implication that ***the little money*** I have isn't really sufficient for my needs. But *I have **a little** money* strongly implies that ***I have enough*** money (or at least, a useful/significant amount of money).

Comment: (So obviously the article is important if I want to point out that I gave ***a*** little thought to my previous comment! :)

Comment: Few is opposed to many, so a few miles is not far, but many miles is a long way. The actual ranges of numbers would depend on your mode of transport. A couple is two (approximately when you are measuring and not counting), with no implication about whether it is a large or small distance.

Comment: *Why does he can throw the ball a few hundred feet suggest that such a throw was unremarkable?* Without further context,  it doesn't; that source is incorrect. If you insert *only*, you can make it unremarkable.

Comment: You suggest that "He can throw it few feet (off/away/etc.)" is grammatical - not sure, but in any case such a use of "few" is very awkward and uncommon - i.e. "few" (without an article) before a unit of measure.  Instead of saying "This box weighs few pounds" most would say "This box only weighs a few pounds" or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the [quantifiers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/571016/15299) *few* and *a few* are idiomatic, and opposed.

- ***few*** (no article) is a [negative trigger](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299); it licenses [NPIs](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/NPIs.pdf) like *ever*: *Few **ever** visit his birthplace*.
- ***a few*** does not license NPIs: **A few ever visit his birthplace*

Both quantifiers refer to small integers, but *few* is a maximum and refers to the smallness of the integer, while *a few* is a minimum, not a maximum.

Where there are ***a few***, there may be more; but where there are ***few***, there may be even fewer.