# Is "a row of trees" singular or plural?

Tags: meaning

I'm confused as to what should be the correct sentence here.

1. A row of trees were to be planted in front of the house.
2. A row of trees was to be planted in front of the house.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(noun) of (noun): subject-verb agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570999/noun-of-noun-subject-verb-agreement) Google searches strongly suggest that plural override (a row of X's were ...) is favoured for X's = trees, though I'd take each case on its merits. 'A row of trees was blocking my view' but 'a row of trees were slowly succumbing to the incredible gale'.

Comment: Did they plant trees? Or did they plant a row? Depends on who was there watching.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that ***notionally***, each tree is planted, so it would be ok to say that

> *A row of trees **are** planted*.

Most often, however, when the row is considered as a whole and the action of the verb hints to the whole, not to each item of the whole, then you can safely use the singular.**A** row means **ONE** row, so it is singular.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/row) has a similar example:

> *A row of tall fir trees* ***shuts*** off the view of the street in front.

It is as the rule of verb agreement with the *collective nouns*:

> When all the members of a collective noun are ***performing an action as a unit*** (and that’s usually the case), use a ***singular verb***.
>
> - The chamber orchestra often plays at the Art Centre.
>
> When the members of a collective noun are ***performing an action as individuals***, use a ***plural verb***. In this case, all or some members of the group are doing something independently of the other members; the group is not acting together as a unit.
>
> - The orchestra are tuning their instruments. ([source](https://www.touro.edu/departments/writing-center/tutorials/verb-agreement-with-collective-singular-nouns/#:%7E:text=Singular%20and%20plural%20verbs%20with,Our%20family%20enjoys%20this%20restaurant.))